# How to fill in Stripe Element form via Splinter?

Tags: python, selenium, integration-testing, stripe-payments, splinter

These are Stripe Elements: https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/elements/quickstart.

I'd like to test them using Splinter, but can't fill in the inputs while preserving order of the characters.

Answer (score 0):

```
def fill_in_stripe_input(browser, iframe_name, input_name, value):
    # every Stripe Element is in a separate iframe
    with browser.get_iframe(iframe_name) as iframe:
        # get the internal Selenium element.
        selenium_input = iframe.find_by_css('input[name=' + input_name + ']').first._element
        # just send_keys('424242...') doesn't work, because order of characters may get mixed up
        for character in value:
            selenium_input.send_keys(character)

from splinter import Browser
browser = Browser('chrome', executable_path='/usr/local/bin/chromedriver')
fill_in_stripe_input(browser, iframe_name='__privateStripeFrame3', input_name='cardnumber', value='4242424242424242')
fill_in_stripe_input(browser, iframe_name='__privateStripeFrame4', input_name='exp-date', value='0320')
fill_in_stripe_input(browser, iframe_name='__privateStripeFrame5', input_name='cvc', value='999')
```